# What does the slash denote in postgresql virtual transaction identifiers?

Tags: postgresql

For example, my postgresql-main.log contains entries such as the following:

```
process 20234 session 5901502e.4f0a vtransaction  transaction 0 : LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
process 20234 session 5901502e.4f0a vtransaction 2/1 transaction 0 : LOG:  connection authorized: user=postgres database=postgres
process 20234 session 5901502e.4f0a vtransaction 2/2 transaction 0 : LOG:  statement: SELECT d.datname as "Name",
           pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner",
           pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding",
           d.datcollate as "Collate",
           d.datctype as "Ctype",
           pg_catalog.array_to_string(d.datacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges"
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d
    ORDER BY 1;
process 20234 session 5901502e.4f0a vtransaction  transaction 0 : LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.004 user=postgres database=postgres host=[local]
process 20237 session 5901502f.4f0d vtransaction  transaction 0 : LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
process 20237 session 5901502f.4f0d vtransaction 2/3 transaction 0 : LOG:  connection authorized: user=postgres database=postgres
2017-04-26 19:58:07 MDT process 20237 remote [local] session 5901502f.4f0d vtransaction 2/4 transaction 0 : LOG:  statement: SELECT d.datname as "Name",
           pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner",
           pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding",
           d.datcollate as "Collate",
           d.datctype as "Ctype",
           pg_catalog.array_to_string(d.datacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges"
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d
    ORDER BY 1;
process 20237 session 5901502f.4f0d vtransaction  transaction 0 : LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.002 user=postgres database=postgres host=[local]
```

Is there any relation between virtual transaction ids `2/1` and `2/2` above since they share the prefix `2/`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33623171

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do TX and XID fractions stand for in the postgres pgadmin tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621510/what-do-tx-and-xid-fractions-stand-for-in-the-postgres-pgadmin-tool)